# Svg images in html sometimes load and other times do not

Tags: css, angularjs, image, browser

I am using svg icons. Chrome dev tools says "Failed to load resource..." and gives a 404 Error. IE 11 doesn't show them either, but shows no errors in the console window. Per chrome dev tools report, the images are at the paths supplied, so not sure why they wouldn't load. The HTML to pull these in are:

```
<img ng-click="getDocsForCategory(benefit)" ng-src="/ppt/assets/toolIcons/{{benefit.img}}" height="165"><br/>
```

Is this because of how the image is loaded via Angular?

Comment: When the HTML is rendered, what is the value of the src (not ng-src) attribute in your img tag?